# Is this a good way to use module.exports?

Tags: node.js, jsdoc3

I'm curious if the following way is a good approach to use the module.exports functionality.
And if so, what is the best way to add commentary to the code so JSDoc3 can handle it correctly.

I'm currently exporting functions as follows:

Let say we have a module1.js with the following code:

```
/**
* Module1 module
* @module Module1
*/
module.exports = {
    // no jsdoc commentary on purpose
    function1: function(param1) {
        function1(param1);
    },

    /**
    * Function2
    * 
    * Function that will do something
    * @returns {boolean} return value
    */
    function2: function() {
        return function2();
    },
}

/**
* Function1
* 
* Function that will do something
* @param param1 {string} First parameter
*/
function function1(param1){
    console.log(param1);
    // do something
}

/**
* Function2
* 
* Function that will do something
* @returns {boolean} return value
*/
function function2() {
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

and in module2.js

```
/**
* Module2 module
* @module Module2
*/

// Requirements
module1 = require('./module1.js');

/**
* myFunction
* 
* Function that will do something
*/
function myFunction() {
    const param1 = "Parameter1";
    module1.function1(param1);  // call function1 from module 1
}

// just an example of function2 in module2.js
const myBoolean = module1.function2();

// more stuf
```

The problem with this approach is that function1 will now only be described in the jsdoc file as 'inner'(local) function, and function2will now be duplicated in the generated jsdoc file one as 'static' (the exported) and one as 'inner' (local) function.

**Why this approach:**

The reason for this approach is: I want no functionality in exported functions. I want other developers to easily see what functions are exported. So the real functionality is put in the local function below the exports.

**The question:**

Is this a correct way to use the module exports?

And is this a correct way to commentary the code? (for JSDoc3)

**ps: im pretty new with NodeJS**

Comment: This looks fairly standard node.js!

Comment: Why the inner functions though? You could do `module.exports = {function1, function2}` (using [es6 shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)).

Comment: You could also just put the properties on `exports`, like `exports.function1 = function1`